# Как обновить экран android после нажатия на экран?

Tags: java, android, экран

После нажатия на экран происходит некоторое действие, после которого необходимо перерисовать экран. Метод `view.refreshDrawableState()` не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Какой метод, какого класса надо использовать?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    DrawTest drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {        
               drawView = new DrawTest(this);           
               drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);  
               drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
               setContentView(drawView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            this.drawView.desc1.Play(Math.round(event.getX()), Math.round(event.getY()));
            **v.refreshDrawableState();**           
            break;      
          }  
          return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать

```
v.invalidate();
```

Я думаю, это то, что вам надо.

Comment: спасибо! работает